# AGI asterisk python returning 0

Tags: python, asterisk

estoy iniciándome en Asterisk y he hecho un script sencillo de python para probar con los AGIs, no encuentro la manera de devolver una variable a asterisk. En la consola con el debug on, me devuelve 0 pero no la variable que yo he establecido. El dialplan lo tengo bien configurado. Adjunto código.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.8 

from asterisk.agi import AGI

import sys

agi=AGI()

sentence = sys.argv[1]

if sentence == "hola":

    response = "entendido"
else:

    response = "error"

agi.set_variable("response", response)
```

Comment: puedes agregar el log de la ejecucion? Esto para ver como intentas recuperar el valor de la variable. De ya te digo que debes hacer uso de la variables "response" como normalmente se usan las variables en Asterisk.

Answer (score 0):

He visto tu duda, y es que a mi me pasa parecido, pero con el mandar las variables desde asterisk. ¿podrias enseñar el dialplan donde creas la variable, la lanzas al script? Porque yo ejecutando el script normal me funciona, igual es por eso que no te funciona bien en asterisk.

Muchas gracias

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/349604)